# How to convert HTML to JPEG/PNG

Tags: perl

Is there a way in Perl to get the contents of an URL in IMAGE format?

I can `use LWP::Simple` to get HTML, but still can't figure out how to get it in JPEG

Comment: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=610646

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could us the [Wight](http://search.cpan.org/~motemen/Wight-0.01/) module, which allows usage of [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/) from Perl. An example which renders a page to a .png file would look like:

```
use strict;
use Wight;

my $wight = Wight->new;

$wight->visit('http://www.google.com/');
$wight->render('google.png');
```

Another possibility would be to use the Perl selenium API in combination with phantomjs, as described in [this blog article](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_medley/2013/02/headless-selenium-testing-with-phantomjs.html).